# Two point topological space

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, terminology

Is there a standard name for the two point space with precisely one singleton being the only nontrivial open set?

What are its most noteworthy categorical properties?

Comment: Just to symbolize: $(X,\tau) = (\{1,2\}, \left\{\{1,2\}, \{1\}, \emptyset\right\})$?

Comment: @AlexR yes exactly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! It is the [Sierpinski Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space). You will find most answers in the wikipedia link. It is a connected two point set and is really useful for plenty counterexamples and/or constructions.

From a categorical viewpoint the Sierpinski Space represents the functor $X \mapsto \tau (X)$, $f\mapsto f^{-1}$.

Comment: The topology of the Sierpinski space is the [Scott topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_continuity) of the poset $\{0, 1\}$ (partially ordered by $0 \leq 1$).

Comment: I knew about the the representation. Any other interesting categorical property?

Answer (score 2):

The Sierpinski space is a dualizing object which mediates the Stone duality between the category of topological spaces and the category of frames.

http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizing+object